# selecting one check box per row

Tags: javascript, sinatra

I want the user to only select one student per row

I have this for loop to dynamically create rows in a table:

```
for(let i = 0; i<<%=Voter.website_count%>; i++)
{
  let websites = <%=@websites%>;
  let wcount = <%=Voter.website_count%>;
  let cite_row1= websites[i];
  let table=document.getElementById("data_table");
  let table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
  let row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='name_row"+table_len+"'><label><input type='checkbox' class='radio'  name='sites[i]' value='1'>"+cite_row1+"</label></td><td id='country_row"+table_len+"'><label><input type='checkbox' class='radio'  name='sites[i]' value='1'>"+cite_row1+"</label></td><td id='age_row"+table_len+"'><label><input type='checkbox' class='radio'  name='sites[i]' value='1'>"+cite_row1+"</label></td><td></td></tr>";
}
```

I tried this but its not working

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

the table looks like this 
[image]

Comment: because `i` is a javascript-land variable. It does not exist yet at the time you run the ERB code.

Comment: You can't use Ruby variables in JavaScript like this.

Comment: @MarekLipka: it's the other way around :)

Comment: You have to generate a JavaScript array via ERB, e.g. `let websites = <%= @websites %>;`, so you end up with something like `let websites = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];`. You can then access that array via `let cite_row1 = websites[i];`

Comment: @Stefan: or just generate the sequence of `insertRow` entirely in ERB. All the data is on ruby side, it appears.

Comment: @Stefan this worked perfectly! thank you!